# Delete a directory off the server

Tags: command-line, windows-server

I am trying to delete a folder on my server (Windows Server 2003), but the folder has a file in it that I cannot manage to delete.  I used command `del /f desktop.ini` and get an access denied response.  I then did `cacls desktop.ini` and get `DOMAIN\Administrator:R BUILTIN\Administrators:R`.  Does this mean that the administrators just have read-only access?  I tried changing the ownership: `cacls desktop.ini /g everyone:f`, and got access denied.  How can I delete this file or the directory it is in?

Comment: Do you mean... how can you delete that file *without rebooting the server*?

Comment: I don't think I mind rebooting the server.  What would be the problem with that other than it being unavailable for a few minutes.

Comment: It might take longer than a few minutes.  But since you don't have an issue with rebooting the server, you could always boot it to another OS (a LiveCD, for example) and delete the file from there, or boot to Safe Mode... since the issue is one where the OS is "using" the file.

Comment: Are you doing this from the server, or over an SMB session? Can you change the attributes via attrib to remove the read-only flag?